# Intuition for the valuative criterion for properness of morphisms?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I've always been told that the intuition for the valuative criterion for properness is something like this: a morphism $X\rightarrow Y$ is proper if, given a map of a small disk $D$ into $Y$ and a lifting $\alpha$ of $D\setminus\{p\}$ to $X$ for some point $p\in D$, there exists a unique lifting of $D$ to $X$ extending $\alpha$.

In the valuative criterion, we can think of the discrete valuation ring $R$ as representing a germ of the curve around a point, or $D$ in the above picture. Its field of fractions $K$ is the localization at its generic point.

Questions:

1. How can I think of $K$ geometrically as a "punctured germ'' or "punctured disk"? It seems that $K$ is actually a "point'' of $D$, so that the criterion is saying something like, given a lift of the generic point of a small piece of a curve, we can lift to the entirety of the small piece. This makes less geometric sense to me, though. Perhaps one could view the generic point as a non-closed "fuzzy" thing whose closure includes the single closed point $\mathfrak m$ in the DVR and preserve the analogy that way.
2. It seems reasonable to expect the valuative criterion to be able to prove the following: if $X$ and $Y$ are projective (and hence proper) curves, and $p\in X$ is a regular point, then any morphism $X\setminus \{p\}\rightarrow Y$ extends uniquely to a morphism $X\rightarrow Y$. We can interpret this in terms of extending a lift of a small punctured disk (the image of some small punctured disk around $p$ mapped to $Y$). Can the valuative criterion be used to prove this, and if so, how?

I think something like the following works. We have morphisms
$$FF(\mathcal O_{X,p})\rightarrow Y \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb C$$
$$FF(\mathcal O_{X,p}) \rightarrow \mathcal O_{X,p}\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb C$$
that commute. The map $$FF(\mathcal O_{X,p})\rightarrow Y$$ is given by the restriction of the given map $X\rightarrow Y$ to the generic point, since $FF(\mathcal O_{X,p})$ is the function field for $X$ (right?). Then the valuative criterion produces a map $f:\mathcal O_{X,p}\rightarrow Y$.

It seems like this map should be the desired extension, but I'm not sure how to say that precisely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Lemma.** Let $X$ be a variety over $k$. Then $X$ is proper if and only if for every smooth proper curve $C$ and every $U \subseteq C$ open, any morphism $f \colon U \to X$ can be extended to a map $C \to X$.

*Proof.* We extend one point at a time. Suppose $P \in C\setminus U$, and let $V = \operatorname{Spec} B$ be an affine open neighbourhood of $P$. Let $\eta \in C$ be the generic point; note that it is contained in any open. Restricting $f$ to the generic point gives a map
$$\operatorname{Spec} \kappa(\eta) \to U \to X.$$
By the valuative criterion, we can extend uniquely to a map $g \colon \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal O_{C,P} \to X$. Let $W = \operatorname{Spec} A$ be an affine open neighbourhood of $g(P)$ in $X$. Then $g(\eta) \in W$ as well, since open sets are stable under generisation. Thus, $g$ is given by a ring homomorphism
$$A \to \mathcal O_{C,P} = B_{\mathfrak m_P}.$$
Since $A$ is of finite type, we can collect denominators to get a map $A \to B_f$ for some $f \in B$; that is, we get a morphism
$$h \colon D(f) \to X.$$
For every $Q \in U \cap V$, the valuative criterion of separatedness shows that the maps
$$h, f \colon \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal O_{C,Q} \to X$$
agree (since their restrictions to $\operatorname{Spec} \kappa(\eta)$ agree by definition of $g$). Then a simple algebra argument shows that $f = h$ on $U \cap V$. Thus, they glue to a well-defined map on $C \cup \{P\}$.

Conversely, if $X$ is proper, and $f \colon U \to X$ is a map, let $C'$ be the scheme-theoretic image. If $C'$ is a point, then $f$ is constant, so we can trivially extend. Otherwise, $C'$ is a proper curve (being closed inside a proper). Then the normalisation of $C'$ is isomorphic to $C$, since there is only one smooth proper curve with a given function field. Thus, the normalisation map $C \to C'$ extends $f$. $\square$

**Remark.** For a slightly more high-brow version of the same proof, see [this blog post](http://lovelylittlelemmas.rjprojects.net/properness-and-completeness-of-curves/).

**Remark.** To see the analogy with the punctured disk, note that if we identify all nonzero points of the complex unit disk $\Delta$, we get a topological space with two points: one closed point (the image of the origin), and one non-closed point (the image of the punctured disk $\Delta^*$). Thus, removing the origin from this quotient space also gives a one-point space.

Of course, topological spaces behave very differently from ringed spaces, so to some extent the analogy ends there.

In another direction, if we equip $\Delta$ with the sheaf of rings of holomorphic functions, then the local ring $\mathcal O_{\Delta, 0}$ is the ring of convergent power series $\mathbb C\{x\}$. This looks a lot like the localisation $\mathbb C[x]_{(x)}$; for example the completion of both rings is the ring of power series $\mathbb C[[x]]$. This is the beginning of Serre's GAGA principle.

The analogy between the punctured disk and the function field of a curve does not end there. For example, the fundamental group of $\Delta^*$ is $\mathbb Z$, with covers given by $\Delta^* \to \Delta^*$, $x \mapsto x^n$. The absolute Galois group of $\mathbb C((x))$ is the profinite completion $\hat{\mathbb Z}$ of $\mathbb Z$, with extensions given by $\mathbb C ((x^{\frac{1}{n}}))$. This is no coincidence (the key word here is étale fundamental group).

Comment: Thanks! Could you please expand on why $f$ and $h$ agreeing on the local rings means they agree as morphisms on all of $U\cap V$? It seems that maybe you can just pass to affine patches and skip that part, but I might be wrong.

Comment: That is, we may suppose $Y$ is affine, and it suffices to check agreement locally, so we can fix a point $x\in X$ with affine neighborhood $\operatorname{Spec} A$. So now we have two ring morphisms $f,g:B\rightarrow A \rightarrow FF(A)$ that agree as maps to the fraction field (generic point), so we know they must agree as maps to $A$, since the map $A\rightarrow FF(A)$ is injective. Something seems fishy here. Perhaps this is wrong?

Comment: Well, you have to cover $X$ by affine opens, and take their inverse images in $C$. But then you run into a problem: do you take the inverse image under $f$ or under $h$? It is exactly the valuative criterion of separatedness that says that it doesn't matter. (For a counterexample when $X$ is not separated, think of the two inclusions of $\mathbb A^1$ into the line with doubled origin. They induce the same map at the generic point.) In particular, the valuative criterion of separatedness implies that the set-theoretic maps $f$ and $h$ agree; once you know that, your argument works too.

Comment: Ok, great.  Could you please expand on your argument, which seems substantively different? Why does the fact that $f$ and $g$ agree on local rings imply immediately that they agree on their overlap? You checked they agree as maps of sets, and I'm not seeing a quick way to show the sheaf maps also agree.

Comment: My idea was more or less what you said plus my comment above. But I was going to use the somewhat superfluous fact that for a Dedekind domain $A$, we have $A = \bigcap_{\mathfrak p} A_{\mathfrak p}$. Thus a map $B \to A$ is the same thing as a collection of maps $B \to A_{\mathfrak p}$ that agree as maps $B \to K$. This is overkill, as you noted.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help and detailed answer.