# Extending a morphism to a proper scheme using the valuative crierion for properness

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Here's an example I'm trying to work out. Let $f : U := \mathbb{A}^1 -\{0\} \rightarrow X$ be a morphism of schemes, where X is a proper scheme over a field $k$. I am trying to extend this morphism to a morphism from $\mathbb{A}^1 \rightarrow X$. If we consider the morphism $q : \text{Spec} (k) \rightarrow X$ sending the point to $0$, then by the valuative criterion for properness we get a morphism from the local ring $g : \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^1,0} \rightarrow X$ such that $q \circ i = g$, where $i : \text{Spec} (k) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^1,0}$ is the natural map. So now I have a map from the local ring at $0$ - the map $g$, and a map from $U$ - the map $f$. How am I supposed to glue it to a map from $\mathbb{A}^1$? Or am I applying the valuative criterion in a completely wrong way here? Thanks!

Comment: Giving a morphism from $\mathbb{A}^1\to X$ is equivalent ot giving a morphism $f:\mathbb{A}^1-\{0\}\to X$ and a morphism $g:\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^1,0}\to X$ such that in the `intersection' which is just the generic point $\operatorname{Spec} K$, where $K$ is the field of rational functions on the affine line, the two morphisms agree.

Comment: I think [Remy's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1540493/116766) to a related question is very good. The reason Mohan's argument works is also spelled out in the [linked blog post](http://lovelylittlelemmas.rjprojects.net/properness-and-completeness-of-curves/): $\mathbf{A}^1 \setminus \{0\}$ and $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{A}^1,0}$ form an fpqc cover of $\mathbf{A}^1$, and so you get a morphism $\mathbf{A}^1 \to X$ by fpqc descent.

Comment: @TakumiMurayama Thanks for the input. In the related blog post as well as the answer to the related question the fact is used that the point taken out of the curve is closed. Here, the generic point is taken out of $\mathbb{A}^1$. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @baltazar I think both Mohan and I thought by $0$ you meant the closed point given by $x = 0$. But anyway, if you really do want to remove the generic point $\eta$, what scheme structure do you give $\mathbf{A}^1 \setminus \{\eta\}$?